# How can i save state of a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have created a story reading chrome app.
My problem is that whenever the app is relaunched it starts from the first page of the story.
How can i save the last state of the app so that it reloads from the point where it was left?

Comment: localStorage? http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @Mario Not available in a Chrome app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save state of the app using the [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).

Suppose you want to store the index of the page, and you have some function to go to a page:

```
function goToIndex(index){
  chrome.storage.local.set({lastIndex: index}, function() {
    /* actual work */
  });
}
```

And when your app initializes, read the value (note, it's all asynchronous):

```
// Safe default if the storage is empty; should be the first page
var defaultIndex = 0;

chrome.storage.local.get({lastIndex : defaultIndex}, function(result) {
  goToIndex(result.lastIndex);
});
```

Optionally, this will also sync progress across browsers for logged in users, which is a nice feature. You can do it by using `chrome.storage.sync` instead of `chrome.storage.local`, but beware of rather harsh rate limits. It is best to implement your own rate limiting if you use this.